# use variable on array name in for loop in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to print out the element in a list:

```
lst_1=(A B C)
for j in ${lst_1[@]};do echo $j ;done
A
B
C
```

this worked.
But when I use variable on list name, it failed.

```
lst_1=(A B C)
lst_2=(D E F)

for i in 1 2;do \
    for j in ${lst_${i}[@]};do \
        echo $j ;done;done

-bash: ${lst_${i}[@]}: bad substitution
```

Comment: `for l in lst_{1,2}'[@]'; do printf '%s\n' "${!l}"; done`

Comment: no, I want to run it in nested for loop

Comment: `for l in lst_{1,2}'[@]'; do for e in "${!l}"; do echo "$e"; done; done`

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what does the "!" means in "${!l}" ?

Comment: if `var="lst_1[@]"` then `"${!var}"` is like expanding `"${lst_1[@]}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
lst_1=(A B C)
lst_2=(D E F)

for i in 1 2; do
    for j in $(eval echo \${lst_${i}[@]}); do
        echo $j ;
    done
done
```

This make the variable evaluations in 2 steps: first ${i} is substituted. Then the result (which will look like "echo ${lst_1[@]}" because the first dollar was escaped) will be interpreted by the eval command, resulting in the expanded array.

Note: not sure this solution will work in all cases (for example if the array elements will have spaces in them), other solutions might be better.

Comment: The use of `eval` is not required: `ref=lst_$i[@]; for j in "${!ref}"; ...`

Comment: Different solutions require different constructs (the above solution eval, the indirection a separate variable).

Comment: @vladmihaisima thanks! this is exact what I want, I guessed the eval may be useful, but not familiar with it.